# How to remove noise in target detection in opencv. Some noise has mixed with the target contour

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, tracking, face-detection

I want to use findcontours to get a target contours in video and use fitellipse to get a ellpse which just includes target. But in my case, some noise happened behind the target and mix with the target contour. When I use fitellipse to get a ellipse, the ellipse will include the noise and bigger than what i want to get. Just like the pic as follow;[image]
Because sometimes the noise is big, sometimes is small or non-existent, using erode and dilate method can not get a good result as the threshold value is difficult to set. Do you have some good idea to solve this problem, please help me and share your idea! Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Heuristics. What heuristics can be used depends on what your actual "target" within the ellipse is. You haven't told us that.

Comment: I want ot detect a white ball in the water which move by the wind.When the ball move ,some wave happened behind the ball.

Comment: So you actually want to fit a circle, not an ellipse (maybe you can show the image). For this you'll have to estimate the diameter and apply ` fitEllipse` to cancel noise. Or you can take a more direct "circle fitting" approach like the Hough Circle Transform.